# Countif after filterlist Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I would like to see a working example of how to get this formula properly working

=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($P$7,ROW($P$8:$P$5500)-ROW($P$7),,1)),--($P$7:$P$5500="74"))

What im trying to achieve is count all the cells within a range that value is greater than 
zero, but i need to get that working after i apply a filter. I have seen several examples and havent get it working, with the subtotal fx.

Thanks in advance, for any help!

Comment: Sorry @pnuts revised.

Comment: As quoted that formula will always return an error - that's because SUMPRODUCT needs to process arrays/ranges that are the same size but you have $P$8:$P$5500 in the first part and $P$7:$P$5500 in the second - because these are not the same size you get #VALUE! error - I note that Axel's example corrects that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example:

```
    O       P
4
5           6
6   
7   Filter  Data
8   1       74
9   0       74
10  1       74
11  0       74
12  1       74
13  0       74

Formula in P5:
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($P$7,ROW($P$8:$P$20)-ROW($P$7),,1)),--($P$8:$P$20=74))
```

Now you can filter column O and P5 counts only the visible 74.

With function 103 in SUBTOTAL, I really count only the visible cells. This means, also the manually hidden cells are not counted. With function 3 only the out filtered cells are not counted. If cells are manually hidden, they are counted, even if they are not visible.

And I have used the value 74 instead of the text "74". So in my example the column P contains numbers, not text.

How it works:

The formulas within SUMPRODUCT are in array (matrix) context. This means they are handled as if they are used in array formulas.

In array context `{ROW($P$8:$P$20)-ROW($P$7)}` gets `ROW($P$8)-ROW($P$7) = 1, ROW($P$9)-ROW($P$7) = 2, ROW($P$10)-ROW($P$7) = 3` and so on.

`OFFSET($P$7,1,,1)` will get $P$7+1Row = $P$8, `OFFSET($P$7,2,,1)` will get $P$7+2Row = $P$9 and so on.

So `{OFFSET($P$7,ROW($P$8:$P$20)-ROW($P$7),,1)}` gets `{$P$8,$P$9,$P$10,...}`

Within `SUBTOTAL(103, {$P$8,$P$9,$P$10,...})` it counts 1 if `{$P$8,$P$9,$P$10,...}` is visible and 0 if not.

So the SUMPRODUCT results in

```
SUMPRODUCT({1,0,1,0,1,0,0,...}, --($P$8:$P$20=74))
```

The `{($P$8:$P$20=74)}` results in `{TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,...}` depend of if $P$8:$P$20=74. The `--` (`*-1*-1`) gets this in numeric context, so that the TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0.

So the SUMPRODUCT finally results in

```
SUMPRODUCT({1,0,1,0,1,0,0,...}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,...})
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thanks you so much Axel, with your example i quietly understand it right this time, i wasnt getting that the offset row should the title of my column. I got everything running, but could you please explain in details whats behind of this part right here: OFFSET($P$7,ROW($P$8:$P$20)-ROW($P$7),,1)),--